# Changing the preferences of Gnome-terminal globally

Tags: i3, gnome-terminal, regolith

Is there any way to change Gnome-terminal settings, such as transparency, globally, so that I won't have to set it again and again after restarting i3-wm?

I'm using Regolith Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I've figured it out. Only thing you need to do is insert these two lines into your Xresources file:

```
gnome.terminal.use-transparent-background: true
gnome.terminal.background-transparency-percent: [some number]
```

Comment: Xresources file? Where would I edit that?